# ATT DSL and Juniper SRX w/Integrated Modems

Tags: adsl, juniper

Here's what I'm trying to accomplish:

Existing Setup:

2 x Netopia ADSL 3347 Gateways that are each connected to a Juniper SSG140 via Ethernet. The Netopia boxes appear to each have a PPPoE interface bridged to the Ethernet side of things that is taking one of the 5 IP addresses in the /29 they've assigned to us. The SSG has two untrust interfaces set with equal cost routing to give us a pseudo load balance.

Desired Setup:

New Juniper SRX220 w/integred ADSL PIM cards

Frustration:

The DSL interface at-1/0/0 and at-2/0/0 appear to be configured properly, physical sync is fine. When I configure the PPPoE interface (pp0 unit 0 and pp0 unit 1) if I set the family inet section to negotiate address I get a /32 address and the connection does work, but this is not my assigned range it appears random as it changes if I down the interface and reconnect. If I set the family inet address section to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/29 it takes the configuration and the tunnel comes up bet there clearly is no peer to communicate with. My thought is that under negotiate I'm being given some kind of default gateway and I need to put it in statically.

Where I get confused is when I look at the Netopia's routing table for reference and it shows the default route to be in another network thats it not connected to.

Any thoughts? I figure I'm missing something simple.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: This guy pulled it off with a NetScreen... could I do the same? http://www.juniperforum.com/index.php?topic=5847.0

Comment: I'd also add that it is my intention to static NAT some of these IP's to devices in the trust or a DMZ zone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ultimately solved my issue:

http://kb.juniper.net/InfoCenter/index?page=content&id=KB17223&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1294708451673